# Split a delimiter in a list of list when delimiter may be both present and absent

Tags: python, list, loops, split, delimiter

Is it possible to bypass an if statement when delimiting a list that has both a presence and absence of a ',' delimiter? I would like to delimit each list in this the list of list below when a ',' is present. However, some of the lists don't have a ','.

```
oldcode = [['a, b'], ['a'], ['a,b,c']]

oldcode_split = []

for code in oldcode:
    oc = code.split(',')
    oldcode_split.append(oc)
print oldcode_split
```

I would like this result:

```
oldcode_split = [['a','b'], ['a'], ['a','b','c']]
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is *not* an issue of some items not having a comma in them, this is an issue that you can't use `split` on a list: you use it on the string contained in the list, like `oc = code[0].split(",")`. Why do you have a list of lists that each contains one element in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes it is possible, use a simple list comprehension:

```
In [63]: lis = [['a, b'], ['a'], ['a,b,c']]

In [64]: [x[0].split(',') for x in lis]
Out[64]: [['a', ' b'], ['a'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

using `map()`:

```
In [66]: map(lambda x:x[0].split(','),lis)
Out[66]: [['a', ' b'], ['a'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

Comment: Fore purely cosmetic reasons, sometimes I wish python had some sugar for accessing lists with only 1 item in them.

Answer (score 0):

```
     python 3.2

    1. [("".join(i)).split(",")for i in oldcode]

    2. import re

     [re.split("\W+",str(i).strip())[1:-1]for i in o]
```

### though the methods i used to have the result is not so good. but Diversity is beauty.